# "Fetching" SMTP connections

Tags: security, smtp

I'm struggling to word this question so please bear with this preamble.

We use a product called Serv-U from Solarwinds as an sFTP server as it has a gateway feature I find really handy. The server component is installed on the internal network. The gateway is installed in the DMZ. The gateway does not require any ports to be open from the DMZ to the internal network, only from the internal network to the DMZ. The server component monitors the gateway and when a connection is attempted from an external address, the server bridges that connection onto the internal network. I don't completely understand how it does this, although it must be some sort of reverse tunnel. It works flawlessly.

My questions are:

1. Is there a product that does this with SMTP?
2. Is it possible?
3. Is there a security weakness in this configuration?

Thanks for listening.

Comment: Which OS do you use/prefer? Are you ready for a bit of scripting?

Comment: I'm competent in Linux, though we're more Windows-centric where I work.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is something to bridge a tcp connection, HAProxy can do this for you.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/616998/configuring-haproxy-for-smtp-traffic describes how do to it.  The weakness in a basic proxy is that an attacker is hitting your interior machine's app directly instead of brokering it through something in the DMZ.  You might instead think about hosting a simple store-forward MTA in the DMZ that will accept the email and sent it on to your interior host -- this is safer as the outside is not talking directly to your interior. http://mireka.org/ is an example.